# How to use variable text in a Binding StringFormat?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, string-formatting

So I would like to have a variable StringFormat in a binding, but I'm not sure how to do that.  I don't mind if it's XAML or code behind.  Here's what I currently have:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockSpellSkill" Text="{Binding CurrentValue, StringFormat=Spell: {0}}" />
```

However, I would like to be able to change the prefix "Spell:" to, for example "Skill:" based on a variable in my model.  The easiest way would be if I could do it in code behind something like this:

```
if (true)
{
    TextBlockSpellSkill.StringFormat = "Spell: {0}";
}
else
{
    TextBlockSpellSkill.StringFormat = "Skill: {0}";
}
```

but I couldn't find any way to just set the string format from code-behind.  If there's a good way to do it in XAML I'm cool with that too!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `StringFormat` that you are using is for `Binding`. What you want to do is something like this

```
var textBlock = new TextBlock();
var binding = new Binding("CurrentValue");
binding.StringFormat = "Spell : {0}";
textBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
```

Comment: Awesome! Still new to the whole binding paradigm and XAML syntax for it makes my head hurt :)  I'll accept when it opens up

Comment: @Tevis It's gonna be hard in the beginning but you'll see the awesomeness of bindings. Just keep doing it :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in a number of ways.  One way would be to use a `Style Trigger`.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockSpellSkill" >
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding CurrentValue, StringFormat=Spell: {0}}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeFlag}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding CurrentValue, StringFormat=Skill: {0}}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Another option would be to use an [ValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your binding.